# What is the smallest Lipschitz constant of a Lipschitz retraction of $\ell_\infty([0,1])$ onto $C[0,1]$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, banach-spaces

By Theorem 1.6 in the book ["Geometric Nonlinear Functional Analysis" by Benyamini and Lindenstrauss](https://books.google.com.ua/books/about/Geometric_Nonlinear_Functional_Analysis.html?id=lXZ95EKwjYUC&redir_esc=y), the Banach space $C[0,1]$ is a Lipschitz retract of the Banach space $\ell_\infty[0,1]$. Unfortunately, the proof does not give any upper bounds on possible Lipschitz constants of the retraction. So, the

> **Problem.** Give some upper bounds on the smallest Lipschitz constant $L$ of a retraction $r:\ell_\infty[0,1]\to C[0,1]$. Is $L\le 20$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, as we have this theorem of Nigel Kalton:

> Let $K$ be a compact metric space. Then $C(K)$ is an absolute 2-Lipschitz retract.

Please see [1] for details.

[1] Kalton, Nigel J. "Extending Lipschitz maps into C (K)-spaces." Israel Journal of Mathematics 162.1 (2007): 275-315.

Comment: @TarasBanakh, you are most welcome. I remember that I had used this result some time ago.

Comment: On the first page of this paper the constant 20 (by Lindenstrauss) is mentioned. It is the same as was asked by OP. May I wonder, is it something special to have Lipschitz constant 20?

Comment: @FedorPetrov, I think it simply the estimate that follows from the Lindenstrauss' (non-optimal) proof. Kalton wanted to make a case that his result indeed strengthens the original result.

Comment: @FedorPetrov The constant 20 appears in the book of Benyamini and Lindenstrauss, where they construct a uniformly continuous retraction of $\ell_\infty(K)$ onto $C(K)$ which is locally Lipschitz with constant 20 at a neighborhood of $C(K)$ in $\ell_\infty(K)$. But even this local constant 20 cannot be traced to give a reasonable global Lipschitz constant. So the result of Kalton is very nice and exact (2 cannot be further improved).